# Python "Wheat and Chessboard legend"

Tags: python, for-loop, range

There is an old "Wheat and chessboard" problem:
If a chessboard were to have wheat placed upon each square such that one grain were placed on the first square, two on the second, four on the third, and so on (doubling the number of grains on each subsequent square).

```
grains = 1
for square in range(1, 64+1):
print(square, grains)
grains *= 2
```

- This will give the complete range of the "chessboard" with the number of grains.

How can i program it that the user will type in a specific square number and get the correct number of grains for each specific tile? Exp: input = 5 the answer is 16 and so on
**I need to use the range-Function.** if possible.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Use the number you got from the user instead of 64 in your `range(1, 64)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the user input the square number in a variable `square`

Then we can do:

```
grains = 2 ** (square - 1)
print(grains)
```

Basically, you'll observe that each square has `2^(n-1)` grains in it. So this way it simplifies the problem.

**(Assuming the squares start from 1,  not 0)**

Comment: Thanks. It helps. But is it possible to use it with the range-Function?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But this is the simplest way. As you might have noticed, I am not using any loops, so the time to evaluate the result is pretty much constant and is a single-step operation, unlike the case where I use range over a loop.  However, "range" can be useful when printing grains for ALL the squares.

Answer (score 0):

The number of grains on a tile = `2^nrTile`.
So ask input and return `2^input`.